# Spring @RequestBody for subclass. Alternative to @JsonTypeInfo?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, jackson

Trying to acheive this

```
@RequestMapping
public String helloWorld(@RequestBody Parent interface){
    // do something with interface

}
```

where `Parent` is an Interface and `Child1` and `Child2` are implementations.

Because those are 3rd-party library .class files, I cannot use `@JsonTypeInfo`

Is there any workaround for this case?

Comment: ObjectMapper is the best ( jackson jar). import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

YourClassName yourObjectname= objectMapper.readValue(JsonString,YourClassName.class);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use Jackson Mixin to provide jackson annotations to third party/untouchable classes.

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations

This example is rather old, and provided from here but it still looks correct from the last time I implemented a MixIn,

http://programmerbruce.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html

Example 5 from above,

```
{     "animals":
    [
       {"type":"dog","name":"Spike","breed":"mutt",        
       "leash_color":"red"},
       {"type":"cat","name":"Fluffy",
           "favorite_toy":"spider ring"}
     ]
   }


import java.io.File;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonSubTypes;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonTypeInfo;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonSubTypes.Type;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

public class Foo
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(
        new CamelCaseNamingStrategy());
    mapper.getDeserializationConfig().addMixInAnnotations(
        Animal.class, PolymorphicAnimalMixIn.class);
    mapper.getSerializationConfig().addMixInAnnotations(
        Animal.class, PolymorphicAnimalMixIn.class);
    Zoo zoo = 
      mapper.readValue(new File("input_5.json"), Zoo.class);
    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(zoo));
  }
}

class Zoo
{
  public Collection<Animal> animals;
}

@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
    property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @Type(value = Cat.class, name = "cat"),
    @Type(value = Dog.class, name = "dog") })
abstract class PolymorphicAnimalMixIn
{

}

abstract class Animal
{
  public String name;
}

class Dog extends Animal
{
  public String breed;
  public String leashColor;
}

class Cat extends Animal
{
  public String favoriteToy;
}
```

You can use `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` or  `Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean` to register the MixIn within Spring Boot.

A working example of the above in Spring Boot world can be found here with tests verifying successful POST of Cat/Dog, e.g. the concrete implementation of the parent class.

https://github.com/Flaw101/springbootmixin

Comment: Ok, thank you for the right direction. However, I am still looking for a way to use this in a Spring context with @RequestBody.

Comment: `@ReuestBody` uses Jackson to map to the target class, dependant on the incoming payload. If you setup your `ObjectMapper` to use the `MixIn` it will work.

This is the correct way to do what you're asking. See http://www.baeldung.com/spring-httpmessageconverter-rest for more info on how incoming requests get mapped to expectations.

Comment: Thanks Darren, I read the instruction in the link, but still puzzled at how to achieve this. It does mention creating a custom converter but I do not see any MixIn, ObjectMapper or Inheritance related stuff. Also I am using Spring boot with no XML configs, the guide suggests I need to have one.  Could you please provide a code sample as I am more confused?

Comment: @JunPark here's a working example you can clone that I put created from the above example implemented into Spring Boot, https://github.com/Flaw101/springbootmixin
There's a ControllerTest that posts, a Cat and Dog, and get's read into an Animal object in the controller.

Comment: Thanks Darren, I was able to solve the issue with the directions you provided. However I am seeing that when I use MixIn with an instantiable superclass, that takes precedence over the subclasses. Is there a way to enforce the MixIn annotations to take precedence?

Comment: @JunPark may be dependant on the classes you are trying to map. I can remove the abstract modifier from the `Animal` class and tests still pass. is the JsonType info being set correctly to determine what subclass it needs to use? You may want to edit my example to be more inline with your needs to try and get a closer example.